# Hibernate property update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When i use the hibernate property `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`, even a consult doesn't work.

the hibernate log is:

```
: jul 27, 2017 8:28:18 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@6974a715] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
```

If i remove the update property, i can do the consults, but generate tables don't. I can't generate tables and i really need this.

This is my `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="#####" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                      value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@#####:#####:#####"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="#####"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="#####"/>

            <!-- propriedades do hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect"/>
            <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>

            <!-- atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

            <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `even a consult doesn't work`?

Comment: @ujulu, nothing happens. using this property, everything returns only this log that i put in the post. EVERYTHING.

Comment: If the schema is generated once, `update` will not change anything except you change the structure of your entity, e.g., adding/removing a field, adding/removing annotations, etc.

Comment: the schema was created by(i don't know)... this entity is mine, i created it.

Comment: so, i created all java project and this persistence.xml with this property and the entity `@Entity public class entity{//attrs}` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with 'create'??

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```